# Understanding `echo $((0x63))`

Tags: bash

I was searching for a way to convert hexadecimal via command line and found there is a very easy method `echo $((0x63))`.

It's working great but I'm a little confused as to what is happening here.

I know `$(...)` is normally a sub-shell, where the contents are evaluated before the outer command.

Is it still a sub-shell in this situation? I'm thinking not as that would mean the sub-shell is just evaluating `(0x63)` which isn't a command.

Can someone break down the command for me?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$(...)` is a command substitution (not just a subshell), but `$((...))` is an arithmetic expansion.

When you use `$((...))`, the `...` will be interpreted as an arithmetic expression. This means, amongst other things, that a hexadecimal string will be interpreted as a number and converted to decimal. The whole expression will then be replaced by the numeric value that the expression evaluates to.

Like parameter expansion and command substitution, `$((...))` should be quoted as to not be affected by the shell's word splitting and filename globbing.

```
echo "$(( 0x63 ))"
```

As a side note, variables occurring in an arithmetic expression do not need their `$`:

```
$ x=030; y=30; z=0x30
$ echo "$(( x + y +x ))"
78
```

Comment: Also note that because `$((...))` conflicts with command substitution, one has to remember to write `echo "$( (echo x; echo y) | tr xy yx)"` instead of `echo "$((echo x; echo y) | tr xy yx)"` (even though some shells will still accept the latter, YMMV).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas And how do you make `$(( ))` produce output which is affected by word splitting or globbing?

Comment: @HaukeLaging,  `IFS=9; echo $((0x63))`. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) (`What about [ $# -gt 1 ]` section)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a subshell, but arithmetic evaluation.  From [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ((expression))
>
> The  expression  is  evaluated according to the rules described below
>   under **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION**.  If the value of the  expression  is 
>   non-zero,  the  return  status  is  0;  otherwise  the return status
>   is 1.  This is exactly  equivalent to let "expression".

Comment: `((...))` is not quite the same as `$((...))`. Both does arithmetic evaluation, but the latter is replaced by the resulting value as a string.